# Is there any way to slowdown the receiving stream in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, time, stream

I am getting 10-12 integer events in a second but I only need 5. so I would like to take avg of all the events incoming in 200ms and then return one event every 200ms in a new stream. How can I do this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest checking out the StreamGroup class which allows you to manipulate streams. Here's the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/StreamGroup-class.html

Comment: StreamGroup doesn't seem very helpful. I am trying to figure out something using Timer class.